# how to use --max-old-space-size command in polymer while building large project

Tags: node.js, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

when I run polymer build after implementing more components, it runs out of memory.

Error message

```
 <--- Last few GCs --->

 122257 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.3 (1422.6) -> 1364.3 (1438.6) MB, 2263.8 / 
0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
124485 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.3 (1438.6) -> 1364.3 (1438.6) MB, 2227.9 / 
0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
126853 ms: Mark-sweep 1364.3 (1438.6) -> 1372.2 (1422.6) MB, 2367.6 / 
  0.0 ms [last resort gc].
 129104 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.2 (1422.6) -> 1380.1 (1422.6) MB, 2251.1 / 
0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

  Security context: 0x2e91707cfb39 <JS Object>
2: NewPromiseCapability(aka NewPromiseCapability) [native promise.js:175] [pc=0x34d60057703] (this=0x2e9170704381 <undefined>,O=0x2e91707c3041 <JS Function Promise (SharedFunctionInfo 0x2e9170774f51)>)
3: all [native promise.js:269] [pc=0x34d600e1f88] (this=0x2e91707c3041 <JS Function Promise (SharedFunctionInfo 0x2e9170774f51)>,S=0x1c7a750742a9 <JS Array[0]>)
4: /* anonymous */(aka...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap 
out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [polymer]
 2: 0x10d6aac [polymer]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [polymer]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) 
 [polymer]
  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, 
 v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [polymer]
  6: 0x99c0eb [polymer]



  Aborted (core dumped)
```

If we increase --max-old-space-size it might solve the issue!! But how to set --max-old-space-size while building?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-bundler/issues/394

Answer (score 5):

solved with this command, I'm using Linux

```
node --max-old-space-size=2048 /usr/local/bin/polymer build
```